# Swift Firebase Firestore Data in Tableview

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am having trouble getting my tableView to load with data from Firebase Firestore. I iterate through comments documents in the `generateMore()` function and assign add a comment as an `AttributedTextComment` to the array. But when I set the array in the `viewDidLoad()` for the view controller, the array stays empty and I cannot figure out why. Thanks for any help! Also I am using the SwiftyComments library that can be found on Github if that can help with understanding the code.

**EDIT**: The array within the `generateMore()` function fills up with all the Firestore data, as intended, but `allcomments` in the ViewController never gets set equal to that array for some reason.

```
class RandomDiscussion {
    var comments: [AttributedTextComment]! = []
    var colRef: CollectionReference!

func generateMore() -> [AttributedTextComment] {
    var arr: [AttributedTextComment]! = []
    colRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("pictures/TKIiXdontufmDM1idbVH/comments")
    let query = colRef.whereField("body", isGreaterThan: "")
    query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("error")
            return
        }
        else {
            for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(doc.documentID) => \(doc.data())")
                let com = AttributedTextComment()
                com.posterName = doc.get("username") as? String
                com.body = doc.get("body") as? String
                com.upvotes = doc.get("upvotes") as? Int
                com.downvotes = doc.get("downvotes") as? Int
                arr.append(com)
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
            }
        }
    }
    return arr
}
}


class RedditCommentsViewController: CommentsViewController {

    private let commentCellId = "redditComentCellId"
    var allComments: [AttributedTextComment] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.register(RedditCommentCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: commentCellId)

        tableView.backgroundColor = RedditConstants.backgroundColor

        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(loadList), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)

        allComments = RandomDiscussion().generateMore()
        currentlyDisplayed = allComments


        self.swipeToHide = true
        self.swipeActionAppearance.swipeActionColor = RedditConstants.flashyColor

    }

    override open func commentsView(_ tableView: UITableView, commentCellForModel commentModel: AbstractComment, atIndexPath indexPath: IndexPath) -> CommentCell {
        let commentCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: commentCellId, for: indexPath) as! RedditCommentCell
        let comment = currentlyDisplayed[indexPath.row] as! RichComment
        commentCell.level = comment.level
        commentCell.commentContent = comment.body
        commentCell.posterName = comment.posterName
        //commentCell.date = comment.soMuchTimeAgo()
        commentCell.upvotes = comment.upvotes
        commentCell.isFolded = comment.isFolded && !isCellExpanded(indexPath: indexPath)
        return commentCell
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor = RedditConstants.flashyColor
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = .white
        UIApplication.shared.statusBarStyle = .lightContent
    }
    @objc func loadList(){
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Comment: Can we see your "loadList" function?

Comment: May be problem was at whereField("body", isGreaterThan: "") . It's campare by alphabet order for isgreaterThan constraint

Comment: @Oliver Just updated it. It's just trying to reload the tableView

Answer (score 0):

If there isn't any problem with the Firebase Query, your function may be failure.

Using completionHandler with for statements and Firebase queries makes things very easier.

Convert your generateMore function to this:

```
func generateMore(completionHandler: @escaping (Bool, [AttributedTextComment]) -> Void) {
    var arr: [AttributedTextComment]! = []
    colRef = Firestore.firestore().collection("pictures/TKIiXdontufmDM1idbVH/comments")
    let query = colRef.whereField("body", isGreaterThan: "")
    query.getDocuments() { (querySnapshot, err) in
        if err != nil {
            print("error")
            completionHandler(false, [])
        }
        else {
            for doc in querySnapshot!.documents {
                print("\(doc.documentID) => \(doc.data())")
                let com = AttributedTextComment()
                com.posterName = doc.get("username") as? String
                com.body = doc.get("body") as? String
                com.upvotes = doc.get("upvotes") as? Int
                com.downvotes = doc.get("downvotes") as? Int
                arr.append(com)
            }

            completionHandler(true, arr)
        }
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // ...
        allComments = RandomDiscussion().generateMore { (success, comments) in

        if success { 

        currentlyDisplayed = comments
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        // OR
        NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "load"), object: nil)
        }
     }

        //...

    }
```